# Apache - rewrite jpg to URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Hi im trying to do redirect from .jpg file to specific URL address but it don't work. Can sb help me?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)\.jpg [NC]
RewriteRule ^/up/([\w]*\.jpg)$ /file?name=$1[R=301,L]
```

for eg.: i have image www.mydomain.com/up/image.jpg

and i would like to redirect it under: www.mydomain.com/file?name=image.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)\.jpg [NC]
RewriteRule ^up/(.*)\.jpg/?$ /file?name=$1.jpg [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The redirection works, but now the image is not displayed. Im trying to display those image on page from which im redirecting. Im using Zend Framework.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond` is totally redundant here, you can match this pattern in `RewriteRule` itself. Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^up/(.+?\.jpe?g)$ file?name=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Also you may not need `R=301` here since you don't want to expose your internal handling of image to clients.